# What do "git checkout \*" and "git commit -" accomplish?

Tags: git

I'm seeing `git checkout \*` and `git commit -` referenced on an [online tutorial](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-git-to-synchronize-and-backup.html). What do these accomplish? (It doesn't seem immediately obvious from the man pages.)

Comment: It would be better of you first think about the question and then post it instead of reediting the main part of the question over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to issue the command

```
git checkout *
```

then your shell would expand the `*` glob before `git checkout` is executed. For example, if you had files **a.txt**, **b.txt**, and **c.txt**, the shell would expand that to

```
git checkout a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

before running it. Instead, when you use `\*`, the `*` is escaped and passed directly to `git checkout`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage:

```
git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>
```

> When <paths> or --patch are given, git checkout does **not** switch
>   branches. It updates the named paths in
>              the working tree from the index file or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit). In this case, the
>              -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an error. The 
>              argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for
>              the given paths before updating the working tree.

In here he is escaping the glob `\*`, to prevent bash expanding it; so it can be used by git to be expanded against what is in the index.

EDIT (after question update):

and about `git commit -, 'canonical version'`: 
it is just a typo (notice how <kbd>,</kbd> is just beside <kbd>m</kbd> key) for `commit -m '...'`.....

Actually `git commit --file -` would read its input from stdin, when used for piping data coming from some other command; but it is not what was intended in your example.

Comment: I understand now that passing "\*" prevents bash from glob expansion before it is passed to git. But I still don't understand what git is doing with this. What do you mean "so it can be used by git to be expanded against what is in the index"?

Comment: You have your working directory containing files; the git index contains a file list (of files which have been added to the index). If you do `git checkout *` bash will match `*` with the current working directory, expand the command and execute actually `git checkout file1 file2 file3...`. If you do `git checkout \*`, git will receive the glob and match it against the list in the index, performing the operation described in the yellow box above, with all files that match (all of them in this case).